# is the pallet bounties migration only required if the pallet name has changed?

Tags: storage-migration

I noticed that the pallet bounties has a migration that updates the storage to version 4, but it seems only to migrate the storage to a new prefix based on a pallet name change. Is it only required if the pallet name changed? If the old and new pallet names are the same it does nothing, not even update the storage version, so if the pallet name didn't change should I create a dummy migration just to set the storage version to 4?

Thanks.